# google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() - Is it Possible to specify The Idle Time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, python-idle

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function()
```

Is it Possible to specify The Idle Time ?

Thanks Terran

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately this feature doesn't exist. The best way to achieve this is to use a combination of [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [`window.clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

I'd suggest something like this (untested):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
   var idleTimeout = window.setTimeout(onIdle, timeout);
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
     window.clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
   });
});
```

Note the use of `addListenerOnce`, which fires only the first time the event occurs.

Comment: Thanks Broady - I'll look in to using this then and if any changes are needed I'll post back here.... Terran

Comment: Nice, but I'm not really sure if the 'bounds_changed' event handles all cases when the map could stop being idle... for example the user might just click to it to add markers (if there is such code)... @Terran might want to test this also.